# select max from multiple columns mysql with corresponding column value

Tags: mysql

I have a query result in MySQL with the following structure

```
 class | eng  | math | sci | ss  | kisw
-------+------------+-------------------
 4N    | 80.2 | 41.2 |96.3 |52.0 | 41.5
 4S    | 52.3 | 45.2 |98.5 |65.2 | 85.3
 5N    | 74.3 | 87.0 |69.9 |74.2 | 84.5
 5S    | 87.5 | 45.6 |72.3 |25.6 | 10.3
```

The above query gives subject scores for each of the classes. I want to perform a query that will give me the best class per subject. This is what the end result should look like :

```
subject | class | score
--------+-------+-------
eng     | 5S    | 87.5
math    | 5N    | 87.0
sci     | 4S    | 98.5
ss      | 5N    | 74.2
kisw    | 4S    | 85.3
```

I have tried looking at these questions but none of the answers addresses the issue of selecting a maximum value for many columns with a corresponding column value

[Select MAX value from column and corresponding value from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228127/select-max-value-from-column-and-corresponding-value-from-another)

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using union all

```
select 'eng' as subject,class,eng from tablename 
where eng =(select max(eng) from tablename)
union all
select 'math',class,math from tablename 
where math=(select max(math) from tablename)
union all
select 'sci',class,sci from tablename 
where sci=(select max(sci) from tablename)
union all
select 'ss',class,ss from tablename 
where ss=(select max(ss) from tablename)
union all
select 'kisw', class,kisw from tablename 
where kisw=(select max(kisw) from tablename)
```

Comment: is there a better way to do with if the above is a MySQL result rather than a table? I have updated my question.

Comment: What is your table, then?

Comment: Niaje @BensonKiprono. Do you mean you want to manipulate a mysql result from a previous query?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT subject, class, score
        FROM   TABLE )
PIVOT  (MAX(score) AS max_score FOR (subject) IN ('eng' AS eng, 'math' AS math, 'sci' AS sci, 'ss' as ss , 'kisw' as kisw));